# How do I snap an object to an empties world position in the bge

Tags: python, game-engine, import

to simulate re-spawns I need to get an object from the scene named "Target" (this is where the player will spawn at)

and get the sensor connected to the python controller, then when the sensor is triggered, move its Owner (the player) to the "Target" object.

thanks for the help! BLEND' ON!

Comment: What do you mean with "import"?

Comment: I've changed the question, does this make more sense?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> get an object from the scene named "Target"

```
scene = bge.logic.getCurrentScene()
objects = scene.objects
target = objects["Target"]
```

> get the sensor connected to the python controller

```
sensors = bge.logic.getCurrentController().sensors
sensor = sensors["sensor name"]
```

> when the sensor is triggered

```
if sensor.triggered:
```

or do you mean "when the sensor evaluates positive condition"? (Which makes more sense)

```
if sensor.positive:
```

> move its Owner (the player) to the "Target" object.

```
sensor.owner.worldPosition = target.worldPosition
```

I hope it helps

You can find more details on BGE Python in [the BGE Guide to Python Coding](http://blenderartists.org/forum/showthread.php?249757-Prof.-Monster-s-BGE-Guide-to-Python-Coding)